# Get 3 random numbers with probabilities from a list js

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, random, discord.js

I'm trying to get 3 alternate numbers in a list. Everything turns out fine, but what I try is that there is a chance that the same 3 can come out.

I plan to add this function to a discord.js command based on the number of votes a person has.

I currently do this.

```
let cosmetics = ["item1", "item2", "etc..."......];

const items = []

for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
  items.push(cosmetics[Math.floor(Math.random() * cosmetics.length)])
```

This returns 3 items at random. But how do I control the probabilities that all 3 are the same?
By the way ... the list of cosmetics has a quantity greater than 1500 items. That's why I'm interested in the probabilities (2%, 5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, 25%, 30%)

Comment: I don't understand your probabilities. Are you trying to control the chance at which your code generates doubles and triplets?

Comment: I do not understand English at all.
My idea is that people can get the same results. (Something like the casino machines), they may be lucky in that they come out 3 of the same, or semi lucky in that they come out 2 of 3 of the same. Or bad luck: all different.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function weightedRandom(prob) {
  let i, sum=0, r=Math.random();
  for (i in prob) {
    sum += prob[i];
    if (r <= sum) return i;
  }
}

let cosmetics = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
let index = weightedRandom({0:0.6, 1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2});
console.log(cosmetics[index]);
```

Comment: this applies to short lists.
My list has over 4,000 items.
And I am trying to choose 3 at random but there is a chance that the 3 will be repeated